# Has a company ever used a drug test as a cover to test for pregnancy or disease?

Tags: pregnancy

Some people claim that unscrupulous employers have used drug tests as a cover to use a woman applicant or employee's urine to determine if she is pregnant (or has other medical conditions that might lead to claims on the group health insurance).

In particular, the [ACLU claims](https://www.aclu.org/racial-justice_womens-rights/workplace-drug-testing) that in the Washington DC police department admitted it had done this:

> In 1988, the Washington, D.C. Police Department admitted it used urine samples collected for drug tests to screen female employees for pregnancy - without their knowledge or consent.

If this one case is true, is this something that happened many times, or is it an isolated incident?

Comment: I've put this On Hold in response to a flag. There are two possible questions here. Notable one: "Did the Washington Police admit to doing this?" and an unnotable one "Is this a wide problem?" If you want to ask the former, let's focus the title/question. If you want to ask the latter, let's find some notable claims of this.

Comment: @Oddthinking, a quick Google search will find numerous claims that this practice exists. Try "drug test pregnancy job", for example.  I chose to cite a claim by the ACLU because they claim that it happened at a specific institution at a specific time.  I would like to ask the question, "In general, does it happen today?".  How might I go about editing this question to make it a better fit for this site, or is that even possible?

Comment: I'm trying to find a useful question in here. I did that search. I found many claims it *could* be used that way. I found the ACLU claim it *has* been used that way in a specific case. I found a [1995 claim](http://www.ukcia.org/culture/piss_gui.php) that "employers are using urinalysis to test women for pregnancy. Pregnant women are getting laid off or denied employment after taking such a test." So, there are three directions we could go: 1) is it possible? 2) did it happen in Washington? 3) has it ever happened? (which the second question would resolve).

Comment: Your title asks question 3. The body goes for question 2, then suddenly diverts to an unnotable claim - is it common? (Note: I found another reference claiming that it is illegal in the US, but that's probably neither here nor there.)